# Swift: How I can partially apply generic function?

Tags: swift, generics

i have some generic function, and i need to get a link to the generic function with a specific generic type.

```
// my generic function
func messageResult<M: SwiftProtobuf.Message>(_ dto: M?) {
    result(try? dto?.serializedData())
}

// then i try get link to the function with a specific generic type 
// but i throw error
let dtoResult = messageResult<Dto.OpenResult>
```

error message: `'>' is not a postfix unary operator`

ide highlighted: `let dtoResult = messageResult<Dto.OpenResult>`

how i can write it correctlly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the generic argument by type annotating `dtoResult`

```
let dtoResult: (Dto.OpenResult) -> () = messageResult
```

Comment: Or also, `let dtoResult = messageResult as (Dto.OpenResult) -> ()`. IDK which is preferable

Comment: @Alexander I prefer explicitly setting the resulting type